Why doesn't this component fill the entire width?
I am confused why the first button doesn't fill the whole width here:


<div style="display:flex;">
  <button style="width:100%;"> </button>
  <button style="flex-shrink: 0;"> </button>
  <button> </button>
</div>



Why does flexbox interrupt the width?

the first button does exactly 100% of the width alowed to him by the flexBox model. what did you expect ?

@MisterJojo No it doesn't. Do you not see the two buttons on the same line?

Of course I see them! They are outside the part of the space allowed of the first button! When you use a display:flex on a parent, the size of the parent is not used as a reference. each child element have its own distribued space, where the integrity of its content takes precedence. The result you get with your buttons on the same line is therefore normal for flex display, as you have defined it here. So there is no defect in the display here.But rest assured, with the answer that you validated, I ended up understanding your wording error in your question.

@MisterJojo got it thanks

It fills the entire width available to it by its flex container, which has to leave room for the remaining items in the container.
If you're expecting the items to wrap, the default value for flex-wrap when not specified is nowrap.  You can set a custom value to allow the items to wrap:


<div style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;">
  <button style="width:100%;"> </button>
  <button style="flex-shrink: 0;"> </button>
  <button> </button>
</div>




the first button doesn't fill the whole width because of how flexbox distributes space. By default, flex items have flex-shrink: 1, allowing them to shrink. When you set width: 100% on the first button, it initially takes up all space, but then flexbox redistributes the space to accommodate the other buttons.

You're asking the wrong person in the wrong place. Please put a demo back in your answer to demonstrate your solution.

It does. As reflected in your code snippet.


<div style="display:flex; height: 50px;">
  <button style="width:100%;"> </button>
  <button style="flex-shrink: 0;"> </button>
  <button> </button>
</div>



However, if you're expecting the two sibling buttons to shrink to zero, then you have to remove the default padding and borders on button elements.



<div style="display:flex; height: 50px">
  <button style="width:100%;"> </button>
  <button style="padding: 0; border: 0;"> </button>
  <button style="padding: 0; border: 0;"> </button>
</div>



